# Is it possible to make Nginx two condition

Tags: nginx

Can i make two condition for invalid referer and not "exoplayer" ?

For example:

```
 if ($invalid_referer && !="exoplayer") {
     return 403;
 }
```

Comment: What is "exoplayer"?

Comment: android m3u8 player